# Do pinto beans just ferment quickly?

Tags: food-preservation, beans

I make bulk pinto beans as follows:
Soak beans overnight in salty water

Cook until tender, adding chopped onion and Serrano pepper

Drain completely, place onto baking sheet to cool (~100F, this takes about 15 min)

Place baking sheet in freezer until cold, then place into ziploc bag

Okay, pretty normal. I can't really do anything more with the temperature aspect.
However, within 3 days the beans have a noticeable, but somewhat faint, farty odor when I open the bag.
I usually just mix them cold with freshly cooked rice, which immediately brings them up to temp.
I'm only on the fourth day now and I can smell fart just from the beans in my stomach!

Is this normal? What can I change to make them last a bit longer. I suppose I could just freeze them but I'd like to hear from those more knowledgeable about the fermentation process.

Comment: How do you store the beans in the bag? Fridge? Counter?

Comment: fridge. freezer i dont think I would have this issue but im asking out of curiosity

Comment: Why drain them? Have you tried storing them in the liquid instead? I make beans often and I've never had a problem as you describe, but I always store them in the liquid.

Comment: mostly because I dont have lexans, and water has such a high heat capacity that draining them really cuts down on the cooling time. also Im fairly sure that bacteria would enjoy water more

Comment: Maybe I should post this as a new question, but… why salt water? I know you definitely shouldn't boil beans in salt water as it makes them hard, but what's the thinking behind soaking in salt water?

Comment: i read it test kitchen mag or something. the beans hold their constitution a bit better https://www.cooksillustrated.com/how_tos/9576-brining-beans-in-half-the-water

Comment: Ah, OK. I'll have to give that a try sometime. Thanks.

Comment: You say you keep them for 3 days in the fridge after which they go off - this is the normal state of affairs for cooked food, see the linked question.